# Close Xamarin.Forms DisplayAlert

Tags: c#, xamarin, task, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to close a Xamarin.Forms [DisplayAlert](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/pop-ups/) without user interaction?
There is no `CancellationToken` that I can provide.
So how can I cancel it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't with the default Xamarin alert.

Have a look at the [ACR.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) NuGet package. It *does* have support for `CancellationToken`s. Or if you're feeling brave dig in the Xamarin.Forms repo on GitHub and create a pull request yourself!

Answer (score 0):

i have created custom displayalert you can use task call back TaskCompletionSource as xamarin build DisplayAlert [from it](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5a2cb89775e4de1fe8b8e1d4b673612e5f41f94a/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Page.cs)

```
    public async Task<bool> ShowDialogAsync(string title, string message, string acceptMessage, string cancelMessage)
                {
                    Grid ShowDialogMessage = null;
                    Grid CurrentPageGrid = (App.Instance.CurrentPage as ContentPage).Content as Grid;
                    TaskCompletionSource<bool> result = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                    try
                    {
                        ShowDialogMessage = GenericView.CustomDisplayAlert(message, CurrentPageGrid.RowDefinitions.Count, CurrentPageGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count, () =>
                        {
         //here you can add your implementation   
                            CurrentPageGrid.Children.Remove(ShowDialogMessage);

  result.SetResult(true);

                        },
                        () =>
                        {
         //here you can add your implementation      
                            CurrentPageGrid.Children.Remove(ShowDialogMessage);
                            result.SetResult(false);
                        }, title, acceptMessage, cancelMessage);

                        CurrentPageGrid.Children.Add(ShowDialogMessage);
                        return await result.Task;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(title, message, acceptMessage, cancelMessage);
        #if DEBUG
                        throw ex;
        #endif
                    }

                }
```

in my method i added actions to implement the call back ,, method signature

```
public static Grid CustomDisplayAlert(string message, int rows, int columns, Action acceptAction, Action cancelAction, string title = "", string acceptMessage = "", string cancelMessage = "")
        {   .....
```