# Xamarin - inspect current page to see if Display Alert or Action Sheet are present

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Does Xamarin give us something out of the box to determine if there is already a popup/alert visible on the current page?

I understand that I can set flags for this, but ideally would want to do something cleaner.

Comment: Not sure you real plan to see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37941023/close-xamarin-forms-displayalert) helps, just guess still needs some help from other packages.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know if there is anything simpler, I did it like this :

```
public async static Task<bool> HasPopupPageOpen(string pagePopup)
{
  var collectionPoupStack = Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.PopupStack;
  PopupPage pP = collectionPoupStack.Where(w => w.ToString().Contains(pagePopup)).FirstOrDefault();

  return pP != null;
}
```

Obs: using Rg.Plugins